# How to search in multiple fields in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Suppose I have documents with the following structure.

```
{
  "text": "This is the road I mentioned",
  "created_at": "2015-01-11T05:30:36.000Z",
  "language": "en",
  "character_count": 25,
  "userInfo": {
    "id": 553669398108446700,
    "user_id": 2803103316,
    "user_screen_name": "blue555555"
  }
}
```

I need to search for a keyword say "road" in the field "text" and another keyword "blue555555" in the field "user_screen_name". This is basically searching on multiple fields, how can I do that in elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) queries inside a [`bool/must`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) query so that both constraints match.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "text": "road"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "userInfo.user_screen_name": "blue555555"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As one of the search is of query behavior and other is filter behavior , I would suggest filtered query.

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "road"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "userInfo.user_screen_name": "blue555555"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

}